# Find certain websites that I visited

Tags: web, search-engine, history, google-search

My question might be off-topic but I've been looking for hours and don't know where else to ask.

Obviously, the choice would be to look in my browser history but there is nothing I'm looking for. I visited one blog last week that I want to read again but neither Google nor my browser history can find it.

I only remember certain topics the blog author was writing about, but it is almost strange that I don't find them. I think I got the link to it from Hacker News. Then there was a blog with a software engineer writing very long rants about how programmers should not join projects and amusing rants about work in software engineering, and on the front page of his blog he showed that he had gotten an email message that he should speak to a therapist instead.

I think it's strange that it's 2023 and I cannot find my way back to a webpage I visited last week. Is there a software that can help me? I even looked in the "Wayback Machine" and got even more confused.

Comment: No better bet than just history. Did you delete it from that accidentally? Else it should be max 30 mins of scanning through it. Google with `""` exact phrase matching could also help, if you remember anything longer.

Comment: I found it yesterday out of coincidence when going through old notes I had. It's peculiar that I could not find it in my history when I had copy pasted the link to a note. It was not in my history of Firefox but it's possible that I looked in the wrong timeframes. I thought software could be more helpful but in this case, I got lucky.